# How to display data automatically without having to use a button?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, to get the data from the firebase database, I use button to get the data and display them into textview. However, every time i uploaded data, i need to click the button in order to get the data to be displayed.

Therefore, is there a way to display the data right away after the upload session instead of clicking the button to display them?

Below code shows how i display the data at the moment by clicking button which works successfully.

Thanks!

```
fetch=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bFetch_Schedule);
    fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dayRef.child("Subject").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    textViewSubject_Schedule.setText(value);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

            dayRef.child("What is in our class?").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    textViewWhat_Schedule.setText(value);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which gets the value from Firebase and then stops listening. If you use the same code with `addValueEventListener` it will keep receiving updates.

```
dayRef.child("Subject").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        textViewSubject_Schedule.setText(value);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

You'd typically put this code in a lifecycle event of the activity, such as `onCreate` or `onStart`.

Comment: @Mehmed Your answer contains the same basic information. I just gave a more basic explanation and copy/paste sample, since OP seemed to need that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `addValueEventListener()` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

The listener you provided to `addValueEventListener()` is called each time the data changes.

The listener you provided to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is called once with the value of the data at the location.

You may also want to check `addChildEventListener()`. All information available at the related [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query).

Comment: thanks for replying, then how to implement this? or just replace the code line?

Comment: Just change the function name from `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to `addValueEventListener` as a start.

Comment: can you at least provide example? or maybe altered my coding would be useful

Comment: You want to click once to load data and expect it to be updated automatically, am I right?

Comment: i dont want to click anything except upload, i dont want to click fetch button everytime to display the data

Comment: this page is for displaying while the other page is for uploading. so the upload page works flawlessly. so this page currenltly are needed to click fetch button in order to display data